# Where can I find the Curve25519 derive method implementation?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, x25519

I'm playing with python library [cryptography](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography) using [openssl](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) and [x25519](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve25519).

By looking for the code of [`EVP_PKEY_derive`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/17197a2f61d04314b465b71a4ce164b5e219f15c/crypto/evp/exchange.c#L333)

I can see:

```
ret = ctx->op.kex.exchange->derive(ctx->op.kex.exchprovctx, key, pkeylen,
                                       SIZE_MAX);
```

What I'm looking for is the implementation of the derive method for x25519.
But impossible to find it in the openSSL code.

Does someone know where can I find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at the OpenSSL 3.0 (master branch) code. That code is in state of flux at the moment because all the internal plumbing is being rewritten. You are probably better looking at the 1.1.1 branch.

The X25519 derive code is here:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/bf4006a6f9be691ba6eef0e8629e63369a033ccf/crypto/ec/ecx_meth.c#L684-L695

With most of the interesting code in this file:

https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable/crypto/ec/curve25519.c

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found where the code lives: [libcrypto](https://github.com/openbsd/src/tree/master/lib/libcrypto) which can be found in the [openbsd project](https://github.com/openbsd).

**EDIT: The below paragraph is for classic Elliptic curve, not X25519**
Please see @Matt Caswell answer

EVP_PKEY_derive method can be found [here](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/lib/libcrypto/evp/pmeth_fn.c#L333).
It uses:

```cpp
return ctx->pmeth->derive(ctx, key, pkeylen);
```

leading to [definition](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/lib/libcrypto/ec/ec_pmeth.c#L516):

```cpp
.derive = pkey_ec_kdf_derive,
```

leading to [pkey_ec_kdf_derive](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/lib/libcrypto/ec/ec_pmeth.c#L249)
and finally to [pkey_ec_derive](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/lib/libcrypto/ec/ec_pmeth.c#L210):

```cpp
static int 
pkey_ec_derive(EVP_PKEY_CTX * ctx, unsigned char *key, size_t * keylen)
{
    int ret;
    size_t outlen;
    const EC_POINT *pubkey = NULL;
    EC_KEY *eckey;
    EC_PKEY_CTX *dctx = ctx->data;

    if (!ctx->pkey || !ctx->peerkey) {
        ECerror(EC_R_KEYS_NOT_SET);
        return 0;
    }

    eckey = dctx->co_key ? dctx->co_key : ctx->pkey->pkey.ec;
    if (!key) {
        const EC_GROUP *group;
        group = EC_KEY_get0_group(eckey);
        *keylen = (EC_GROUP_get_degree(group) + 7) / 8;
        return 1;
    }
    pubkey = EC_KEY_get0_public_key(ctx->peerkey->pkey.ec);

    /*
     * NB: unlike PKCS#3 DH, if *outlen is less than maximum size this is
     * not an error, the result is truncated.
     */

    outlen = *keylen;

    ret = ECDH_compute_key(key, outlen, pubkey, eckey, 0);
    if (ret <= 0)
        return 0;

    *keylen = ret;

    return 1;
}
```

which uses [ECDH_compute_key](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/lib/libcrypto/ecdh/ech_key.c#L95) as expected.